# How to parse a XML URL in Python and loop through each item?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a XML URL that i am trying to read in Python.
The XML contains a large dataset of around 50-60K products.

Example of two products in the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<channel>
    <title>
        Google Shopping NL
    </title>
    <description>
        Google Shopping NL
    </description>
    <pubDate>
        Tue, 10 Jan 2023 09:30:35 -0000
    </pubDate>
    <item>
        <ecomm_prodid>123456</ecomm_prodid>
        <g:gtin>8714567834276</g:gtin>
        <g:price>17.95 EUR</g:price>
        <title>Unique Living Teddy plaid - Bruin - 200x150cm</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ecomm_prodid>56789</ecomm_prodid>
        <g:gtin>871987731105</g:gtin>
        <g:price>29.90 EUR</g:price>
        <title>Tristar OV-1431 oven 35x25 - 800W - 230V</title>
    </item>
```

I want to read the XML and loop trough each 'item' to check if that item contains a certain  'ecomm_prodid' so that I can retrieve the 'g:gtin' of that product. Is that the best way, and if so, how would I be able to achieve that?

Kind regards:)

Comment: https://lxml.de/

Comment: You might want to post actual valid xml. In the example above, the prefix "g" is nowhere defined, so this will not even parse.

Comment: I can't post the actual .xml as it contains all the products and its info of the company. The prefix "g" is defined here:
``` 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
```

Comment: Not asking you to post the actual xml, just asking to post valid XML so people don't have to fix it to provide you a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ElementTree to parse your XMl and to iterate over the  items in your XML, then use find on those items to get the corresponding sub-tags.

Example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmldata = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<channel xmlns:g="base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <title>
        Google Shopping NL
    </title>
    <description>
        Google Shopping NL
    </description>
    <pubDate>
        Tue, 10 Jan 2023 09:30:35 -0000
    </pubDate>
    <item>
        <ecomm_prodid>123456</ecomm_prodid>
        <g:gtin>8714567834276</g:gtin>
        <g:price>17.95 EUR</g:price>
        <title>Unique Living Teddy plaid - Bruin - 200x150cm</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ecomm_prodid>56789</ecomm_prodid>
        <g:gtin>871987731105</g:gtin>
        <g:price>29.90 EUR</g:price>
        <title>Tristar OV-1431 oven 35x25 - 800W - 230V</title>
    </item>
</channel>
"""

xml = ET.fromstring(xmldata) # use ET.parse(filename) to parse from file
for item in xml.findall('item'):
    prodid = item.find('ecomm_prodid').text
    gtin = item.find('g:gtin', {"g": "base.google.com/ns/1.0"}).text
    # Now you can access prodid and gtin
    print(f"{prodid} - {gtin}")
```

Comment: I copied your code but get an error:


`xml = ET.parse('https:LinktoFile.xml')
for item in xml.findall('item'):
    prodid = item.find('ecomm_prodid').text
    gtin = item.find('g:gtin', {"g": "base.google.com/ns/1.0"}).text
    print(f"{prodid} - {gtin}")`

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    xml = ET.parse('https:LinktoFile==.xml')
  
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https:LinktoFileQ==.xml'

Comment: Did you read through the documentation of ET.parse (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse)? Does it say anywhere there, that you can pass a URL to the function and it will be automatically retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you can parse the items with read_xml():

```
import pandas as pd

ns = {"xmlns:g" : "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"}
df = pd.read_xml("google.xml", xpath=".//item", namespaces=ns)
print(df[['ecomm_prodid', 'gtin']])
```